# Is there a standard way to call something that's not equal to one, like 'non-zero' is not equal to zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering about that. Would be useful to use something and not-one sounds bulky for some reason.

Comment: You could probably say "non-unital," although since "unit" has a specific meaning in commutative algebra, this is likely to cause more confusion than its worth. Another option would be to say "distinct from $1$."

Comment: If you're using 1 as the identity, you can say "consider a non-trivial element..."

Comment: @PatrickShambayati One usually needs to be careful about that, since $1$ may be nontrivial itself (and $0$ is trivial), for example for matrices.

Comment: @5xum Of course--what I meant was if 1 was the identity, e.g. $(Z/nZ)^*$. I guess group with identity 1 are less common so this wouldn't work

Answer (score 2):

You could with that something is..

.. not equal to one.

.. distinct from one.

.. $\neq 1$.

.. nonidentity (eg. for an element of a group)